# Given a sequence of values to insert into an empty Binary Search Tree, how many ways can that sequence be rearranged to arrive at the same tree?

Tags: tree, binary-search-tree

Let's say the sequence is 8, 3, 10, 7, 9, 12, 5, 11, 4, 6. The resulting tree would look like:

```
       8
     /   \
    3    10
     \   / \
      7  9  12
     /      / 
    5      11
   / \
  4   6
```

How many possible ways can this sequence be reordered so that the end result is the exact same tree? For instance, 8, 10, 3, 7, 9, 12, 5, 11, 4, 6 is one answer.

So far i'm thinking that for each subtree, the order of the two siblings doesn't matter. So 2, 1, 3 is the same as 2, 3, 1. This would apply to every parent-child in the tree. I'm just having difficulty figuring out the recursion and combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the entries in the tree are different, the answer is given by the hook-length formula for trees. It only depends on the shape of the tree.

It reads:

number of possible arrays = n! / product (number of node of the subtrees)

where n is the number of node of the full tree.
For example for your tree:

```
       10
     /   \
    5     4
     \   / \
      4 1   2
     /      / 
    3      1
   / \
  1   1
```

The result is 10! / (10 * 5 * 4 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1) = 756

This is an exercise of Knuth Art of Computer Programming Volume 3: searching and sorting.